# Invoke-Sqlcmd cannot find file when BULK INSERT is used

Tags: powershell

I'm having difficulty invoking the following PowerShell command, from the command line as well as in a script:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -HostName **HOST** -Database **DATABASE** 
-Username **USER** -Password **PWD** -Query "TRUNCATE **THE_TABLE** 
BULK INSERT **THE_TABLE** FROM 'D:\Folder\csvfiles\import.csv' 
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2,  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',TABLOCK)" 
-ServerInstance "tcp:**HOST**"
```

I've copied the CSV file to the parent folder, and then to the root.  Each time, the command fails with the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot bulk load. The file "D:\Folder\csvfiles\import.csv" does not exist.
> At line:1 char:1

This is all part of a script that Task Scheduler runs on an hourly basis.  Often it will run just fine.  Today it has been erroring with more frequency.

I'm stumped. Why can't it find a file that is obviously there? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: What I suggest is you add some directory dump commands to prove it's there. i.e. add this line to your script: `ls D:\Folder\csvfiles` then you can be sure the script can actually see the file and folder

Comment: You aren't opening/generating this CSV from excel by any chance? Because excel will often lock the file if you leave it open

Comment: The file is definitely there.  Another portion of the script (not PS) creates it.  The file isn't open in Excel.  It's running on a server, which does not have Office installed.

More curiously, I copied the csv file from the server to my workstation, and ran the cmdlet again.  This time, the error was a bit more descriptive:

Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\import.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Comment: So your `ls` command shows the file? That will help you rule out a simple mistake.

Comment: Cause when something blindingly obvious doesn't work, the best thing to do is confirm some assumptions by seeing what the script really sees.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there was a related, competing task scheduled that was deleting all of the csv files in the folder at very close to the same time that my script ran.  This turned out to be a case of bad timing.